# Acumular resultados de listas django

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes a todos/as.
Estoy practicando con Django desde hace unas semanas y tengo una pequeña duda que no se como resolver y como llevo un par de días parado con ello, he decidido preguntar por aquí.

Tengo una base de datos que acumular fichajes de entrada y salida de usuarios. Puedo acceder y mostrar los datos de forma correcta cuando resulta que hay una entrada y una salida por día, pero no se como hacerlo cuando existen más de 2 fichajes por día (que es lo habitual).

Puedo mostrar los datos por separado, pero mi intención es mostrarlos en una sola linea del tipo:

"El usuario n ha entrado a las XXX y ha salido a las YYY, ha vuelto a entrar a las XXXX y ha vuelto a salir a las YYYY y ha trabajado n horas en total."

A día de hoy, me muestra los fichajes con la misma fecha, en dos listas separadas, pero mi intención es mostrarlas, como os digo, en una sola.

Os dejo parte del código para ver si me podéis echar una mano a como plantearlo.

```
def MostrarFichajes(request,pk):
    # Calculamos las horas de trabajo, sean cual sean el número de días.
    todosfichajes=list(fichaje.objects.filter(usuario=pk).values_list('fecha',flat=True).order_by('fecha').distinct())
    # Determinados cuantos dias diferentes con fichajes hay en la lista
    rangofichajes=len(todosfichajes)
    # Creamos un diccionario vacio
    resultados=[]
    # Para cada día de la lista, busca los datos de entrada y salida, que están en dos filas.
    for i in range(rangofichajes):
        fichajes=fichaje.objects.filter(usuario=pk,fecha=todosfichajes[i]).values_list('fecha','accion','hora').order_by('-fecha')
        #Buscamos el número de filas por dia que hay (2 filas para un solo día, 2*n para varios fichajes en un solo dia)
        rango=len(fichajes)
        if rango==2: # Es decir, si solo hay 2 registros por día, ejecutamos la rutina
            for j in range(rango):
                if j%2 == 0:
                    fecha=fichajes[j][0]
                    print("El dia de fichaje es ", fecha)
                    hora_entrada=fichajes[j][2]
                    print('La hora de entrada es ',hora_entrada)
                    hora_salida=fichajes[j+1][2]
                    print('La hora de salida es ', hora_salida)
                    diferencial=hora_salida-hora_entrada
                    print('El usuario ha trabajado', diferencial )
                    contexto={
                                'fecha':todosfichajes[i],
                                'hora_entrada':hora_entrada,
                                'hora_salida':hora_salida,
                                'diferencial':diferencial,
                                }
                    resultados.append(contexto)

        if rango>2: #Ejecutamos la rutina si hay más de dos fichajes en un solo dia.
            print("Hay mas de 2 fichajes")
            for j in range(rango):

                if j%2 == 0:
                    fecha=fichajes[j][0]
                    print("El dia de fichaje es ", fecha)
                    hora_entrada=fichajes[j][2]
                    print('La hora de entrada es ',hora_entrada)
                    hora_salida=fichajes[j+1][2]
                    print('La hora de salida es ', hora_salida)
                    diferencial=hora_salida-hora_entrada
                    print('El usuario ha trabajado', diferencial)

                    contexto={
                                'fecha':todosfichajes[i],
                                'hora_entrada':hora_entrada,
                                'hora_salida':hora_salida,
                                'diferencial':diferencial,
                                }

                    resultados.append(contexto)



        # Calculamos las horas de trabajo, sean cual sean el número de días y lo añadimos al diccionario.

    return render(request, "fichaje/verhoras.html",{'resultados':resultados})
```

Actualizado 11/05/2020:
Adjunto el modelo fichaje.py

```
class fichaje(models.Model):
usuario = models.IntegerField(null=True)
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now=True,verbose_name="Fecha")
hora= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name="Hora")
accion = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=12)
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Adjunta el codigo de tus modelos, para ayudarte con mayor facilidad.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Editado.